# Is there anyway I can import only necessary components in vue.js for vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import {Vuetify} from 'vuetify';
import { store } from './store/store';
import { BootstrapVue, IconsPlugin } from 'bootstrap-vue';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css';
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
Vue.use(IconsPlugin);
Vue.use(Vuetify);
new Vue({
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    render: h => h(App),
    store: store,
    router
}).$mount('#app');
```

Right now I am importing the whole vuetify in tou my vue.js project, Is there any way I can just import some specific components? For example, v-data-table,v-toolbar,v-spacer,v-dialog,v-card,v-card-title,v-card-text,v-btn. If I just want to use these components from vuetify , How could I do that in vue.js?

This is what I tried. But it gives me some errors.

```
import {v-data-table,v-toolbar,v-spacer,v-dialog,v-card,v-card-title,v-card-text,v-btn} from 'vuetify';
```

Comment: They have that covered in their documentation: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/treeshaking/

Comment: Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

There is no such possibility, these tags are native to vuetify, imports is just for importing functions from other classes or even other components